# Running big SELECT query on a SSMS(connected to a remote server) floods the C drive's free space

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am trying to run a `SELECT` query on SSMS. The output runs into 10 million + records. But as soon as half of the records are fetched, I get a `System Out Of Memory Exception`. I happened to check Windows Explorer and found that C drive is out of space(few KBs left). Also, as soon as I close the SQL window, the free space in C drive is back to normal. Now, I understand that data is first fetched put into RAM, but want to know why C drive gets filled. I am looking for specific details.

Comment: Virtual memory.  When you computer runs out of RAM, it starts using Hard Drive space as virtual memory.

Comment: It usually helps to output the results into the text window, or even better, a file. The memory requirements of the visual grid are staggerring (it wasn't really designed to show millions of results :)).

Comment: Specifics: http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-memory-performance-metrics-part-6-memory-metrics/

Comment: Why on earth would you need to *render* 10 million rows in Management Studio?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Apparently because I needed to be told in future not to ever do so :) Thanks for the pointers everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Look in C drive for a file called pagefile.sys (C:\pagefile.sys - modify the folder options to show hidden system files). Track the size of this file while you run your query to see if it fills the disk

Comment: I don't see any such file in C drive. I tried searching using wildcards too, but to no avail.